# Guard in a conditional statement

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement

Depending on the value of the `units` parameter, I would like to unwrap the Fahrenheit or Celsius temperature using `guard`. However, I get an error about

> Use of unresolved identifier 'temp'

from the following example code

```
let units = 0

if units == 0 {
  guard let temp = currentDict["temp_f"] as? String else { return nil }
} else {
  guard let temp = currentDict["temp_c"] as? String else { return nil }
}
```

Why does `guard` not work in this example?

Comment: How is `currentDict` defined?

Comment: @appzYourLife currentDict is a dictionary of [String: AnyObject]

Comment: It seems that some code is missing. You should show the all relevant code including the line where the error is given. Your question will be easier to understand as we are now just guessing what you mean.

http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because `temp` was scoped to be within the `if` statement only. Try this instead:

```
let key = units == 0 ? "temp_f" : "temp_c"
guard let temp = currentDict[key] as? String else { return nil }
```

Comment: I like this approach but can you clarify how the first line works? What does the "?" and ":" characters mean?

Comment: It's the [ternary conditional operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID71) or more popularly an inline if. Basically it's equivalent to `if units == 0 { key = "temp_f" } else { key = "temp_c" }`

Answer (score 1):

As others already said, you are probably using `temp` outside of the scope of the `if/else` don't you?

This code will work

```
func foo(units:Int) -> String? {
    let result: String
    if units == 0 {
        guard let temp = currentDict["temp_f"] as? String else { return nil }
        result = temp
    } else {
        guard let temp = currentDict["temp_c"] as? String else { return nil }
        result = temp
    }
    return result
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you using the temp variable outside the if/else statement? That is most likely the source of your problem.